# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space - Stack Trace Meaning

Tags: java, memory-leaks, javafx, jvm

I have a message in a long lived application, a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space.

I want to know the meaning of the stack trace that is displayed after the error message; could I find the issue reading this trace? What is the meaning of the stack trace?

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.nio.HeapIntBuffer.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.IntBuffer.allocate(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.UploadingPainter.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.RenderJob.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.nio.HeapIntBuffer.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.IntBuffer.allocate(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.UploadingPainter.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.RenderJob.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.nio.HeapIntBuffer.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.IntBuffer.allocate(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.UploadingPainter.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.RenderJob.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.nio.HeapIntBuffer.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.IntBuffer.allocate(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.UploadingPainter.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.RenderJob.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your application is just taking up too much memory. If you need to find the specific issue, use a Java Profiler

Comment: Take heap dumps and analyze it in heap dump analyzer like Eclipse Memory Analyzer.

Comment: Thanks Rupesh I am trying with Java Mission Control...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the stack just represents the call that failed to allocate memory, but that might not be the cause. There might be other parts in your program that is leaking memory, or maybe you are opening a big document or if your application is web-based, too many users are running some process and they're using all the memory. jvisualvm.exe (which is included in your jdk) is an excellent tool to analyze memory.

Comment: I've been using Java Mission Control. It's a really good platform to see what's happening on in my app. I saw, in this figure ([link](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-FLVPCNPkOA4/VMlKxkrV6_I/AAAAAAAAJAY/_m0tyfStZ-Y/w958-h593-no/Memory%2BStatus.png)), that a thread called "QuantumRenderer-0" indicates high pressure on allocation process. Do you know the function of this thread?

Comment: QuantumRenderer is related to JavaFX, but the amount of memory allocated doesn't necessarily mean it's overloading the heap, the thread just uses a lot of memory. You need to take a snapshot of your heap to find where is all your memory allocated. Before taking a snapshot, make sure you execute a garbage collect.

Answer (score 1):

**java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space**

Java applications are allowed to use a limited amount of memory. This limit is specified during application startup. Java memory is separated into two different regions.

These regions are called heap ***space*** and ***permgen:***

[image: Diffrent Memory Region]

The size of those regions is set during the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) launch by specifying parameters such as -Xmx and -XX:MaxPermSize. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E22289_01/html/821-1274/configuring-the-default-jvm-and-java-arguments.html) You can see how to set those parameters

If you do not explicitly set the sizes, platform-specific defaults will be used.

So – the “java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space” error will be triggered when **you try to add more data into the heap space area, but there is not enough room for it**.

Note that there might be plenty of physical memory available, but if the heap size limit for this Java program has been hit, the “java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space” error is thrown.

**Causes of java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space**

1. Spikes in usage/data volume.

The application was designed to handle a
certain amount of users or a certain amount of data. Now, when the
number of users or the volume of data suddenly spikes, the operation
which functioned normally before the spike ceases to respond and
triggers the java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space error.

2. List item

A particular type of programming error will lead your application to constantly consume more memory. Every time the leaking functionality of the application is used it leaves some objects behind into the Java heap space. Over time the leaked objects consume all of the available Java heap space and trigger the already familiar java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space error.